# How to set a UserMulti field via a UserField Control?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spfield, spuser

I have a list similar to the usual Tasks Sharepoint List and I introduced the field assigned to as a multi user field like this (I have read somewhere that with Mult option should always be set to TRUE)  :

```
<Field ID="{E942F982-C798-4095-8FD3-AF9A3A374862}" Type="UserMulti" Mult="TRUE" Name="AssignedTo" DisplayName="Assigned To" Group="My Local Group"  StaticName="AssignedTo" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" />
```

to set this field I created a control to get the users:

```
UserField AssignedTo = new UserField();
AssignedTo.FieldName = ActionsCommercialesManagement.Fields.AssignedTo;
AssignedTo.ID = "AssignedToID";
AssignedTo.ListId = TaskListID;
PlaceHolder.Controls.Add(ACAssignedTo);
```

and to recuperate the introduced userS in my AssignedTo userField control I tried to do something like this but it didn't work :

```
newItem = MyList.AddItem();
newItem["AssignedTo"] = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(ACAssignedToID.Value.toString());
NewItemButton.update();
```

So any ideas ????

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is having this problem I just solved it :

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection assignedUsers = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(myWeb, AssignedTo.Value.ToString());
item["AssignedTo"] = assignedUsers;
```

and if you want to retrive the value collection as string all you have to do is :

```
string spliAssignedTo =((SPFieldUserValueCollection)TaskItem["AssignedTo"]).ToString();
```

Hope I helped :)